# Arrow function in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have a problem to understand arrow function 
I know that the arrow function typed like this ()=> 
but i want to know how that the function that we typed the arrow function inside it how to work

like

```
app.listen(3000 , () => console.log('foo'));
```

I want to know hot listen function call the arrow function ? and how it call the arrow function without any name

then if i want to create a function that take an arrow function as a parameter how can i do this ??

Comment: The function gets a name when you use it as an parameter. `function listen(time, my_callback_fn)`. In the body, call it: `my_callback_fn()`.

Comment: "I want to know hot listen function call the arrow function ? and how it call the arrow function without any name" Can you please rephrase this?Question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a callback function, view MDN for documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

The function is named in the parameters of the parent function.

```
function myFunc(callbackFunc) {
    //do stuff!
    console.log("in parent func");
    callbackFunc(); //calls the callback function passed as a param
    console.log("Callback done!"); //If there is async code in your callback function, this may happen BEFORE the callbackFunc() is finished. A common gotcha to watch out for.
}

myFunc(() => { console.log("Doing the callback") });
```

And here is how ExpressJS uses callback functions: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

Apart the important difference between [functions and arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), they are quite similar.

Unnamed:

```js
app.listen(3000 , () => console.log('foo'));
// or
app.listen(3000 , function() { console.log('foo') } );
```

Named:

```js
function aaa() { ... }
// or
const aaa = () => { ... }
```